# How to Get the API credentials for Sofort Testing

Tags: api, configuration, payment

I am integrating the Sofort in to my project i have install the API and now all i need the API credentials for the testing process to put into my configuration as follows:

```
/**
 * API-Key as provided in user account on sofort.com
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_apiKey = '';

/**
 * Complete Config-Key as provided in user account on sofort.com
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_configKey = '';
```

How I can get the developer testing key i have tried by creating an account with Sofort but it is not showing any API section there.

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out as well currently... amazing how some gateways just make it so difficult. I'll post back here if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

look at this:
https://integration.sofort.com/integrationCenter-eng-DE/content/view/full/2513/#h3-3-1

> The API key is provided in the merchant menu at Additional services → API key.